# how to insert an ads into $text?

Tags: php, mysql

i have this code :

```
 <?php include("Hedar.php"); ?>

<?php
    $q=mysql_query("select * from news2 where id = $news2_id ");
    list($news2_ides,$news_id,$name,$text,$stext,$ktext,$dtext,$date,$vews,$path)=mysql_fetch_array($q); 
    ?>
        <img src="upload1/<?php echo $path ?>"/>
         <h2 class="_title"><?php echo $name ?></h2>
         <?php echo $text ?>
        <?php include("Footers.php"); ?> 

------------
```

so as you can see i have a site in PHP code 
so i want to insert 2 adsense code into $text 
i tried to separat this $text to many

but i fail with it 
so anyone can help me to separate this  ( `<?php echo $text ?>` )
thanks a lot
Regards

Comment: mysqli_query is now used instead of mysql_query. You can also use PDO::query or MySQLi::query. You can see the documentation here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0):

If am right you want to display adsense code with the $text variable
so you do:

```
<?php
$text.=$adsense
echo $text;
?>
```

If you are storing your adsense code in $adsense variable

Comment: i want to show ads through the text ( the content of the article ) for example .. 2 lines after that  adsense , then 3 lines then adsense

Comment: Is there a string in the text variable already all you got to do is concatenate the string of the adsense to it like:

     $text.=
     "<br><br><br>".
     $adsense;

you can just use another php file to include your adsense neat.

     <?php echo 
     $text;
      include("adsen
      se");
      ?>

Comment: for wordpress it is more easy like the code below, but for PHP i can't find any code like that ..

<?php $postcounter = 1; 
if (have_posts()) : ?> 
<?php while (have_posts()) : $postcounter = $postcounter + 1; 
the_post(); ?> 
<?php if(4 == $postcounter) 
{ echo ' <div id="adsbetween"> 
<center> YOUR_ADSENSE_CODE </center> 
</div> ' ; 
} ?>

Comment: Relax and look at the code you posted last, thats plain php. Wordpress or not its same.
Just use your record count to know when to display the ad layer.
Wordpress is just a php frame work, it just handles and manages your scripts and map your url. Every other thing it does is just overrated. Relax and focus, we have been saying the same thing all along.
If my answer helped u dont forget to accept it.